# Cypher Create Relationships Between All Elements in each List of Lists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a big list of smaller lists in a JSON file. For each smaller list within the big list, I'd like to create relationships between all the items inside the smaller list.

In this example, I have a list of 2 lists, where each of these has 3 authors.

```
{"title": "Project A", "creators": [{"name": "Dave Chappelle"}, {"name": "Brian Griffin", "org": "ABC"}, {"name": "Dave Jones"}]}
{"title": "Project B", "creators": [{"name": "Dave Chappelle"}, {"name": "Brian Griffin"}, {"name": "Bob Dylan", "org": "NBC"}]}
{"title": "Project C", "creators": [{"name": "Rick Sanchez"}, {"name": "Jack Johnson", "org": "NBC"}, {"name": "Ken Burns"}]}
```

I would like to create a single node for each author, which I have done with the following code:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:/path/to/data.txt') 
YIELD value AS q UNWIND q.authors as author 
MERGE (a:Authors {name:author.name})
```

I would then like to create relationships between creators that worked on a project together. If people work together multiple times, I would like to add a property to that relationship that keeps track of how many times they have worked together.

The following seems to make relationships between all creators, rather than creators who just worked on projects together.

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:/path/to/data.txt') 
YIELD value AS q UNWIND q.authors as author 
MERGE (a:Authors {name:author.name})
MERGE (a)-[c:CO_CREATOR]->() 
ON CREATE SET c.strength = 1
ON MATCH SET c.strength += 1
```

Suggestions for how I can do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is actually creating :CO_CREATOR relationships to new blank nodes, you may want to delete the blank nodes and their relationships first.

One thing to keep in mind is that if you want to create :Project nodes from your source data along with those who co-created the project, you would then have the ability to query through these nodes to find collaborators and the strength of those collaborations.

So assuming you merged in the :Projects as well as the :CO_CREATOR relationships between :Project nodes and :Authors nodes, you could then do something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Authors {name:'Dave Chappelle'})-[:CO_CREATOR*2]-(coAuthor)
WITH coAuthor, count(coAuthor) as strength
ORDER BY strength DESC
RETURN coAuthor, strength
```

And here's the import query you would use to merge in projects and attach them to your already imported :Authors nodes:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:/path/to/data.txt') YIELD value AS q 
MERGE (p:Project {name:q.title})
WITH q, p
UNWIND q.authors as author 
MATCH (a:Authors {name:author.name})
MERGE (a)-[:CO_CREATOR]->(p)
```

EDIT

If you want to use this existing structure to create :CO_AUTHOR relationships between authors, you could do something like this:

```
MATCH (p:Project)
WHERE size((p)<-[:CO_CREATOR]-()) > 1
WITH [(p)<-[:CO_CREATOR]-(a) | a] as coAuthors
UNWIND apoc.coll.combinations(coAuthors, 2) as pair
WITH pair[0] as first, pair[1] as second
MERGE (first)-[:CO_AUTHOR]-(second)
```

This assumes you have APOC Procedures installed. If you don't here's an alternate way to get all combinations of 2 so you can create the relationships between them:

```
MATCH (p:Project)
WHERE size((p)<-[:CO_CREATOR]-()) > 1
WITH [(p)<-[:CO_CREATOR]-(a) | a] as coAuthors
UNWIND coAuthors as first
UNWIND coAuthors as second
WITH first, second
WHERE id(first) < id(second)
MERGE (first)-[:CO_AUTHOR]-(second)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway you can update your answer so that we can do this without creating the project nodes? We specifically want to avoid creating those, and the answer you gave doesn't create relationships between the coauthors, but rather between the project and the coauthors.

Comment: Or, I suppose if I could create the relationships directly between the authors then I could later delete the project nodes. Do you know how I could add another statement that would add relationships between all the coauthors for each project?